# I need a solution for redirecting after the execution of this PHP

Tags: php, forms, redirect, file-upload, upload

I have the following PHP structure :

```
if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;        
           //Writes the information to the database 
            $y = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM files ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") ;
            $a = mysqli_fetch_array($y,MYSQL_ASSOC);
            $index = (int)$a['id']+1;
            $x = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO files (id,title,link) VALUES ('$index', '$title', '$file')") ;
            header('Location:  upload2.php');
            exit();
```

and this structure has the problem that it does not redirect...I guess that the header function does not work like I used it.

I need an alternative solution for the last two lines of my code, so if the file is uploaded successfully I want to write information in the database and after to redirect to a page.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: did you try putting the complete base path?

Comment: You may only redirect if no headers have been sent so far. You have sent headers already ... `echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;`

Comment: You're doing an `echo` before you call the `header()` function. If you have error logging on, your logs most likely show an error like this `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`. Remove the `echo` and try using a full path to the file.

Comment: You cannot use the header function after you echo out information.

Comment: What about removing the `exit();` see if that has any effect

Comment: I tried removing the echo function,still not working,I posted down the error I'm getting. Maybe now you can give me another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are already printing a sentence about the successfull upload so the browser automatically sets an html header. You cannot send header twice so you the redirect is not working at all. You should probably pass the successfull message as a variable in the redirect and use later in the other page after you redirect

```
if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
    $message =  "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;        
    //Writes the information to the database 
    $y = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM files ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") ;
    $a = mysqli_fetch_array($y,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $index = (int)$a['id']+1;
    $x = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO files (id,title,link) VALUES ('$index', '$title', '$file')") ;
    header("Location:  upload2.php?message=$message");
    exit();
```

You can grab the message in the upload page with a simple `$GET['message']`

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I tried it but I get this error message:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at path/upload.php:10) in path/upload.php on line 44

Line 44 is the line with header called.

Any other solution?Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This means you are already printing something somewhere before this point, remove any echo and you should be ready to go

Comment: in the file upload.php I'm not printing anything before this point.
upload2.php is the page from which I'm posting info to upload.php and in this page I'm using echo's to print information from database. My goal is to reaload upload2.php after sending information to upload.php in order the be able to see the last file I added

Comment: If you are using the `$message` as I advised you you could start upload2 checking for `if(isset($_GET['message'])) { print message here } else { print the form here }`